# Forced UIView EndEditing Not Working As Expected

Tags: uiview

I was using the `-(BOOL)endEditing:(BOOL)force` method in a UIView to end editing of the textfields in the view and discovered some unexpected behavior.

I created a simple test program, with a UITextField and two UIButtons. One button calls `[self.view endEditing:YES]` to force editing to end, while the other calls `[self.view endEditing:NO]` to end editing, without forcing.

The File is the textfield's delegate and I have put a simple logging statement in the
`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method.

Here's the code for the buttons and the text field delegate:

```
-(IBAction)doEndEditingForced:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"==========================");
    NSLog(@"In doEndEditingForced");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

-(IBAction)doEndEditingNotForced:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"==========================");
    NSLog(@"In doEndEditingNotForced");
    [self.view endEditing:NO];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"ShouldEndEditing");
    return YES;
}
```

And here's the output I'm getting:

```
2011-10-03 15:36:22.153 Test[94596:207] ==========================
2011-10-03 15:36:22.155 Test[94596:207] In doEndEditingForced
2011-10-03 15:36:22.156 Test[94596:207] ShouldEndEditing
2011-10-03 15:36:26.145 Test[94596:207] ==========================
2011-10-03 15:36:26.146 Test[94596:207] In doEndEditingNotForced
2011-10-03 15:36:26.147 Test[94596:207] ShouldEndEditing
2011-10-03 15:36:26.148 Test[94596:207] ShouldEndEditing
```

In the case of the call to `endEditing` with the `force` parameter equal to `YES`, why is the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method being called at all, and in the case of the call to `endEditing` with the `force` parameter equal to `NO`, why is the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method being called twice?

Answer (score 2):

That happen because endEditing methods dont call any delegate methods for your UITextField or UITextView is just just hide keyboard from your view.