# UITextField endEditing:YES (force) Not Dismissing Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios9

I have several UITextField objects in a custom Date/Time editor control (no spinners). The control is in a UITableViewCell on a modally presented TableViewController during a data record add operation.

If users **cancel** the add operation I need to discard all the data and dismiss the controller and the keyboard if it is showing. I do this by calling this method when the Cancel button is pressed:

```
-(void)cancel
{
    _tempMOC = nil;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

According to the Apple docs, for `UIView endEditing` which state:

> Specify YES to force the first responder to resign, regardless of whether it wants to do so.

my `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` return value should be ignored,  however this is ***not*** the case.

- I have verified with log statements that `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` **is** getting called.
- But, the value is **not** ignored because **only** when this method returns **YES** is the keyboard dismissed.

**The result is that the modal view controller gets dismissed leaving an orphaned keyboard on the screen which can only be gotten rid of by restarting the app.**

This is a problematic pain in the arse because I do various validation operations in here:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)tf
{
    /* Validate data for up to 6 UITextFields in this control. */
    ...
    return valid ? YES : NO;
}
```

In the case where the user hit cancel on the controller, I really need it to ignore the return value, else I have have to do some kind of stupid caveat to figure out that six levels up somewhere the user hit cancel and in that case always return YES.

Any thoughts on what might be going on or if I have missed something... or ugh, I've found yet another Apple bug?!

****** UPDATE ****

This is now reported as radar: 32442632.

Comment: Just an alternative - you could send the `cancel` event to the cell and react there (e.g. setting a flag to cancelled and add `if (cancelled) return YES;`. Another option is to track the current text field using notifications (text fields trigger them) and sending it `resignFirstResponder` explicitly.
Also, make sure you are not sending a `becomeFirstResponder` by mistake after cancelling.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm not really interested in "clever" workarounds, I can think those up on my own. Like I show in my example, I send endEditing:YES. The whole point of that is it is supposed to handle resigning responder for you. Anyway, I want to know why the prescribed and documented behavior is not working and what I might have missed.

Comment: The only thing that comes in mind is that you are activating a text field again after another one loses focus.

Comment: @Sulthan nope, no other textField is getting shouldBeginEditing! It's clearly an iOS bug. The fact that endEditing:YES is NOT ignoring the return value of the shouldEndEditing (which I have proved) indicates it is violating Apple docs. This is a pain because now I will have to post a radar and build a sample App.

Comment: I think it's not a bug. [self.view endEditing:YES] does not considering the presented controller. It is taking reference of controller over which you are presenting this controller.

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla explain your comment more fully. I think you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo Fill the radar. Similar task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640086/forced-uiview-endediting-not-working-as-expected. Try also this instead [viewController setEditing:NO animated:YES];

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas I intend to but I know the first response from Apple will be provide sample App which is not easy given I will have to strip a chunk of the app down to include just those bits and somehow make it break. I guess I will just file and worry about the sample app later. There are some similarities to the case you referenced in that I am seeing 3 calls to textFieldShouldEndEditing for the active UITextField object after the call to endEditing:YES.

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas  And setEditing:NO doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's still happening on iOS 12 